# Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    1 at test.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

I am a beginner and I do no really understand where the thing gets stucked. I presume that somewhere in the `for`.

Some help pls?

**MAIN CLASS**

```
public static ArrayList<Patron> patr_list= new ArrayList<Patron> ();
public static ArrayList<Angajat> angj_list= new ArrayList<Angajat> ();

public static ArrayList<Persoana> pers_list = new ArrayList<Persoana>();

public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader flux_in= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/test/test.txt")));
    String linie;

    while((linie= flux_in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String [] s;
        s= linie.split(";");
        if(linie.contains("angajat"))
        {
            angj_list.add(new Angajat( s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Calendar.getInstance(), s[3], s[4] ));
        }
        else 
            if(linie.contains("patron"))
            {
                patr_list.add(new Patron(s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Integer.parseInt(s[2]), Integer.parseInt(s[3])));
            }

        pers_list.addAll(patr_list);
        pers_list.addAll(patr_list);


        System.out.println(String.format("Nume", "Varsta", "Data_angajarii", "Loc de munca", "Functia"));
        for( Angajat angj: angj_list)
        {
            System.out.println(angj);
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Nume", "Varsta", "Nr de firme", "Nr de angajti"));
        for( Patron patr: patr_list)
        {
            System.out.println(patr);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Persoana CLASS**

```
public String nume;
public int varsta;

public  Persoana (String nume, int varsta)
{
    this.nume=nume;
    this.varsta=varsta;

}
```

public String getNume() {

return nume;

```
}

public void setNume(String nume)
{
    this.nume = nume;
}

public int getVarsta() 
{
    return varsta;
}

public void setVarsta(int varsta)
{
    this.varsta = varsta;
}
```

}

**Patron CLASS**

```
public int nr_firme;
public int nr_angajati;

public Patron(String nume, int varsta, int nr_firme, int nr_angajati)
{
    super(nume,varsta);
    this.nr_firme=nr_firme;
    this.nr_angajati=nr_angajati;
}

public int getNr_firme() 
{
    return nr_firme;
}

public void setNr_firme(int nr_firme) 
{
    this.nr_firme = nr_firme;
}

public int getNr_angajati() 
{
    return nr_angajati;
}

public void setNr_angajati(int nr_angajati)
{
    this.nr_angajati = nr_angajati;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Patronul are" + nr_firme + "firme si" + nr_angajati+ "numar de angajti";        

}
```

**Angajat CLASS**

```
public Calendar data_angajarii;
public String loc_munca;
public String functie;

public Angajat(String nume, int varsta, Calendar data_angajarii, String loc_munca, String functie) 
{
    super(nume, varsta);
    this.data_angajarii=data_angajarii;
    this.loc_munca=loc_munca;
    this.functie=functie;

}

public Calendar getData_angajarii()
{
    return data_angajarii;
}

public void setData_angajarii(Calendar data_angajarii) 
{
    this.data_angajarii = data_angajarii;
}

public String getLoc_munca() 
{
    return loc_munca;
}

public void setLoc_munca(String loc_munca)
{
    this.loc_munca = loc_munca;
}

public String getFunctie()
{
    return functie;
}

public void setFunctie(String functie) 
{
    this.functie = functie;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Angajatul a fost angajat in data de" + data_angajarii + "lucreaza la " + loc_munca+ " si are functia de " + functie;        

}
```

**Text file**

angajat ionel 16 1991,8,4 timisoara director;

patron gigel 45 100 5000;

Comment: Which line exactly is 28?

Comment: Please provide the full source file including the class + package declarations and import statements.  Line 28 in the code snippet provided is a blank line.  Alternatively, highlight or bold the line in the example above that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your text file.

Comment: I provided what you asked. Thank you @peeskillet. Line 28 is:  angj_list.add(new Angajat( s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Calendar.getInstance(), s[3], s[4] ));

Comment: No you didn't, I asked for the text file.

Comment: I already figured out that was the line. And I can tell you your exact problem. It's `Integer.parseInt(s[1])`. I need to see your text file to figure out why It's getting that error though.

Comment: I did. It is at the end of the code.

Comment: I figured out that angajat and patron where not meant to be there because they were ruining the constructor type. Now i do not have the error anymore but it does not run properly. It does not display what it should display. @peeskillet

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided for the case that your input string does not contain a semicolon, and hence the string array returned by split does not have a second element.

The same extends to subsequent fields you access. For example, if you string has only 1 semicolon, there will be no 3rd element in the string array, and so on.

Here a short explanation of the message you are getting:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
   1 at test.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

This tells you the following:

- You tried to access an array element that doesn't exist.
- The wrong index was 1
- It happened in line 28 of the source file Main.java

Equipped with that knowledge, you could've found the error yourself. For, in that line, there is only one array access that uses 1 as index.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `s= linie.split(";");` you assume (a wrong assumption) that there will always be `s[0]`, `s[1]`, `s[2]`, `s[3]` and `s[4]`. (Think about what happens when your input doesn't contain `;`?).

You should verify that `s` have the length you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem'

> angajat ionel 16 1991,8,4 timisoara director;
>
> patron gigel 45 100 5000;

You're splitting by `";"`. The `";"` is at the end of the line. So the `s[0]` is the entire line and there is no `s[1]` or any index after that.

Instead split by this `"[\\s;]"`. That should work. This will split by spaces and semi-colons.

After you split. Do this

```
String name = s[0] + " " s[1]; // This will concatenate the first two indices
```

Examine this chart to see correct indices.

```
new Angajat( s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Calendar.getInstance(), s[3], s[4])

         angajat ionel      16                 1991,8,4         timisoara  director

             name          s[2]                 s[3]               s[4]      s[5]

new Patron(s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]), Integer.parseInt(s[2]), Integer.parseInt(s[3])

         patron gigel      45                 100                      5000

            name           s[2]                s[3]                     s[4]
```